# How to get Dialogflow to say my response from cloud run webhook?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have created a simple intent in DialogFlow where the user asks 'how old someone is' (ex. "How old is David Beckham?").

This is then sent to a cloud run web hook that returns a response: "How am I meant to know?".

When i test this in the DialogFlow console it works fine and the JSON response is returned from Cloud Run to Dialogflow:

**FULFILLMENT RESPONSE**

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "How am I meant to know?!"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem is that DialogFlow is not responding with "How am I meant to know?" in the console. its not responding with anything.

[image]

Is there something else i need to do for this to happen? I assumed this would happen automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That response is only for Google Assistant, you need to add a "default" response in this format:

```
{
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "Text response from webhook"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Every integration has a different format response but they could be used together

Check the docs:
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-webhook